# Kept being directed to HTTP Error 404.13 page despite configuration set in Web.Config

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, maxrequestlength

**Error faced: HTTP Error 404.13 - Not Found/ The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that exceeds the request content length**

Edit: Decided to rephrase and tidy my question.

I kept encountering this error whenever I am submitting files via FileUpload Control. I want to set the file size to 5MB, if selected files exceed 5MB, it will display a error message like (E.g. File exceeded file limit, please try again). Following are my codes.

**

WebPage1.aspx.cs

**

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string gen = "Pending";
        //This portion is for storing files in database
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(FileUpload1.FileName);
        byte[] documentContent = FileUpload1.FileBytes;
        string name = fi.Name;
        //string extn = fi.Extension;
        string filextn = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);

        //This portion is for storing files in folder
        string filepath = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);
        if (filepath.ToLower() != ".pdf" && filepath.ToLower() != ".png" && filepath.ToLower() != ".gif" && filepath.ToLower() != ".zip")
        {
            lblmessage.Text = "Only pdf, png and gif file are accepted";
        }
        else
        {
            //int filesize = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
            if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 5242880)
            {
                //lblmessage.Text = "Maximum size (5MB) exceeded";
                Response.Redirect("Error.aspx");
            }
        }
```

**Web.Config**

- From my understanding maxRequestLength is measured in KILOBYTES (KB)

  ```
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" maxRequestLength="5000"  />
  ```
- And, maxAllowedContentLength is measured in BYTES

  ```
      <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="5242880" />
  </requestFiltering>
  ```

**Other things that I had tried**

- I configure the maxRequestLength in the configuration editor; still failed.

Credit: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/apr/06/configuring-aspnet-and-iis-request-length-for-post-data
https://hoststud.com/resources/how-to-increase-the-maximum-upload-file-size-in-iis.422/

Comment: Is your question "why when I prevent my code to be reached via configuration my code is not executed"?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov you can put in that way. Apologies if my question isn't very clear, I will try to improve.

Comment: You cannot exceed the server limits in your client code.

Comment: Hi @jdweng, how should I improve/modify my codes from here? I had set the limit of 5MB in my web.config file and add a logic in my client code (PostedFile.ContentLength)

Comment: Did you set the server limit?

Comment: Do you mean the IIS - configuration editor (maxRequestLength)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the below configurations

Web.config:

```
    <configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" maxRequestLength="1048576" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>

</configuration>
```

WebForm1.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Sample_File_Upload.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
        </div>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
        <p>
            &nbsp;</p>
        <p>
            <asp:Button ID="UploadFile" runat="server" OnClick="UploadFile_Click" Text="Upload File" />
        </p>
        <asp:Label ID="message" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

WebForm1.aspx.cs

```
using System;

namespace Sample_File_Upload
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void UploadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 5242880)
            {
                message.Text = "Maximum size allowed is 5MB.";
            }
            else
            {
                message.Text = "File uploaded successfully";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, the length set here is for 1GB right? I want to set to 5MB.

Comment: If you set it to 5MB and if the file size is greater than 5MB the request will be failed before processing it. But in your case, you need to show a validation message if the file size is greater than 5MB.

so that we set the config to allow the files greater than 5MB and we validate it later in the logic.

Comment: I see. So how should I improve my WebForm1.aspx.cs on the logic of validating of file size? I have attached my codes with my question.

Comment: Your code should work fine. Just add these settings in the config file

Comment: Hi. I've modified my codes to your web.config codes above. In my webform, it doesn't validate their file despite putting a logic to it. Can you help me?

Comment: where did you implement the logic to check the file size, on the selection of file? or any button click?

Comment: Hi, I will update the button click codes. Pls refer under WebForm1.aspx.cs

Comment: Your code looks perfect, that should validate the file size and show the message if it is greater than 5MB. What is the exact issue that you are facing?

Comment: It is not validating the files I had selected to upload and does not display any error message; instead, it kept redirecting me to the error page

Comment: Here is a sample working code. https://www105.zippyshare.com/v/cOOQyb7F/file.html. download the code from this link

Comment: Hello, I am not able to download the files. Apologies. Are you able to post the codes here?

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. I've tried running this code on a new page. Maybe the problem lies in my code logic. I will look into it. Have a great day.